# get an index from a dict in a list python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I am working on a very basic 'inventory' system in python using a list as the inventory itself and dicts to store the item and how many i have of said item.

What im trying to achieve is if i already have an item in my inv and i pick up more then i dont want a new dict, i want to add the new number of items to the existing.

My function is this:

```
def addToInv(item, number):
if item in inventory:
    newNumber = inventory[item] + number
    slot = {item : newNumber}
    inventory.append(slot)
else:
    slot = {item : number}
    inventory.append(slot)
```

It just appends the list with a new dict.
How could I make this work?

Comment: what is your problem currently? Any error you get? Also please explain the variables, what is `inventory` here in this context? And you are not passing `inventory` to the function, so what are you returning?

Comment: I dont get any errors, but it append the list with a new dict instead of modifying an already existing one. Full code here: https://github.com/goteVagyok/Python_projects/blob/master/Inventory.py

Comment: Can you show the print out of `inventory`? Can you use `inventory` as dict instead of list?

Comment: Why don't you just use a dictionary? You **really** must provide a [mcve], but from your descritption it sounds like you have a list like `[{'item0': 2}, {'item1':1}, ...]` that doesn't make a lot of sense, that is basically taking *the worst* of both worlds when it comes to dict/list objects. You probably just want `{'item0': 2 , 'item1': 1, ...}`, what's the point of the *list*?

Comment: [{"dirt": 4}, {"diamond": 5}, {"dirt": 5}, {"wood": 1}, {"wood": 3}, {"dirt": 5}, {"diamond": 5}] this is how my inventory looks like. im still new to programming and i try to use the basics i know. i tried to create one w/o looking up how to do one and i didnt use a dict instead of a list bc i didnt know you could do that. i will look into it tho and thanks for the answers

Answer (score 0):

To add new items to the list or modify the already included item, you can just modify the content as such:

```
if item in inventory: 
    inventory[item] += number
else:
   inventory[item] = number
```

Answer (score 0):

If I well understood you are working with a single dictionary containing

```
{ item1:nb1, item2:nb2, ... }
```

If yes this should be enough:

```
def addToInv(item, number):
    if item in inventory.keys():
        newNumber = inventory[item] + number
    else:
       newNumber=number
    inventory[item] =newNumber
```